# Eclipse intermittent "cannot be resolved to a type" error

Tags: eclipse

I keep running into a strange intermittent issue with eclipse for the past few days where I will be editing code, save it, and then eclipse starts reporting hundreds (or sometimes thousands) of `MyClassName cannot be resolved to a type` errors. The errors are completely bogus as the classes do exist, and if I do a clean and rebuild on the entire workspace the issue goes away. This is the second workspace in a row that it has suddenly happened to.

Has anyone else ever run into this before? Is there some way to fix this issue without recreating an entirely new workspace (which is extremely frustrating). I'm not entirely sure what keeps happening to seemingly corrupt my workspaces.

[Update]

For clarification this is happening with multiple projects that are all Java (web application) projects using only the standard 'Java Builder.'

Comment: Android? xtend? pure Java? Such behaviour typically depends very much on the builder of the involved plugins.

Comment: They are Java (web application) projects. The only builder used is the standard 'Java Builder'.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging Eclipse gone wrong is a painful task.  I make it a routine habit to reinstall it, sad but true.  The Eclipse Plugin framework tends to lead to these kinds of interactions .  You don't mention what version of Eclipse and if it is EE or standard.

So, I'd suggest you try a fresh install of Eclipse.  Another thing to try is change the JVM you are using to run Eclipse.  The most widely used and tested JVM is still Sun/Oracle Java6.

I have had the best results using the standard version of Eclipse and only adding the EE stuff as needed, ie the Web Developer Tools.

Comment: btw, do you have auto-refresh turned on?  this is one of the annoying defaults that is turned off by default.  go to Window->Preferences, search for "Refresh" and turn on the Refresh options in Workspace settings.

Comment: I'm running the EE edition of Helios (thought I was using Indigo). It's weird that I never had these issues until recently. Also, yea I have that turned on. It's one of the first things I enable on a new workspace. :)

Comment: The only thing I can think of that has changed lately is we moved to building our code with JDK 7, and eclipse itself is still running on JRE 6. Another coworker is using the latest eclipse (actually STS in his case) and running into the same errors. So, my out-of-date eclipse isn't the problem. I am going to change the Java that eclipse is running with and see if things improve.

Comment: Well, it seems changing the JRE that I am using to run eclipse to match the JDK I compile with had no effect.

Comment: Bummer.  What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise. I have got a fresh install of eclipse and new workspace now.  So, I'm going to give that a try and see if the problem comes back.

Comment: Just as an update I still have the problem with a fresh install of Eclipse Juno. :(

Answer (score 0):

If this happens on Windows with a virus scanner being installed, you may want to try excluding your workspace directory from the on-access scanner. I have two colleagues who get very annoying (and not reproducable) build errors quite often, as long as their TrendMicro virus scanner is enabled.

Comment: That is an interesting thought.  Since it is happening with multiple team members this seems like a possibility. Unfortunately I have no control over our virus scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me with Eclipse Neon after git merge with multiple confilicts, I solved the issue with deleting and re-importing my project.